# jsPDF plugin not working in firefox: images showing black box

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jspdf

I am trying to use jsPdf plugin from git to generate pdf of part of my application.
Link to pdf plugin: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
What I am doing is
1) generating combinations of text and images of parts of my application using svg and canvas (jpeg format)
2) adding those images to pdf
3) likewise :

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Paranyan loves jsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
```

4) so i am not able to get the pdf with those images on it, just displaying text and it is showing black box in place of image
(cannot paste my code here)

Tried changing the image format to PNG, then it shows white box instead of black box.

**UPDATE**
The cleaning svg is the solution for this problem. 
But now I am not able to get that how to clean the svg

**Solution**
Add  tag where you create the svg element in your code. Firefox does not understand that svg element is being created until we externally specify the tag.

```
var svg = '<svg>' + chartArea.innerHTML + '</svg>';
```

**UPDATE**
add viewPort, and viewBox attributes to svg to render svg on FF correctly.

**P.S. :

> For no reason, admins banned answering me on questions; for those who
>   need answer for this question, I have updated the question itself with
>   the answer. I do not want anyone to go on spending weeks to search the
>   answer for this particular problem, as I spend weeks to dins the
>   solution. I will be glad if this is helpful for atleast few people.

**

**ANSWER**
All Browsers do not show similar behaviour with SVG. So in chrome adding svg element directly using below statement would work well

```
var svg = objDivToAddToSVG.innerHTML;
```

On Firefox,

```
var svg = '<svg viewBox = "-50 -50 ' + (mainDiv.width*2) + ' ' + (mainDiv.height*2) + '" width="' + mainDiv.width + '" height="' + mainDiv.height + '">' + objDivToAddToSVG.innerHTML + '</svg>';
```

`mainDiv` is `<div>` element wrapping around the svg.

SVG is containing an data which is being converted to image. The image can be seen properly in chrome without any settings. But in firefox, svg attributes viewport and viewbox needs to be specified to let the browser know about the svg dimensions.

For information about viewport and viewbox please follow this [link](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-viewbox/)

In above code for firefox, viewport and viewbox are specified with as follows:
1) viewport - using `height` & `width` properties
2) viewbox - using

```
viewBox = "-50 -50 ' + (mainDiv.width*2) + ' ' + (mainDiv.height*2)
```

i.e. `viewBox = x y min-height min-width`

For all other browsers (tested for opera and safari; not tested on IE)

```
var svg = objDivToAddToSVG.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Update for this : SVg does not scale as expected on firefox, need to set the height width externally.

Comment: Have you worked on IE for this particular problem ?

Comment: I am working on IE support